# Strict monotonicity of the partial derivatives of a strictly convex function

Tags: derivatives, convex-analysis, partial-derivative, monotone-functions

Let $f:\mathbb{R}^n \times \mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a strictly convex function in both its arguments. Suppose $f$ is differentiable in both its arguments. Does the following hold?
 $$\langle \nabla_x f(x_1,y_1)-\nabla_x f(x_2,y_2),x_1-x_2 \rangle >0, \forall x_1,x_2,y_1,y_2\,,$$ where $\nabla_xf$ denotes the gradient of $f(x,y)$ with respect to $x$? In other words, are the partial gradients of a strictly convex function strictly monotone?

Comment: Note that there is no reason to assume that a strictly convex function is differentiable.

Comment: I added the assumption that it is differentiable in $x$ and $y$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no reason to expect such an inequality with arbitrary $y_1, y_2$ in it. For example, let $n=1$, 
$$f(x, y) =  (x+y)^2 + y^2 $$
so that
$$
f_x(x, y) = 2(x+y)
$$
The question becomes: does $x_1 > x_2$ imply
$$
2(x_1+y_1) > 2(x_2 + y_2)
$$
for arbitrary $y_1, y_2$? This shows just how absurd the purported inequality is.